# MockLocation testProvider does not call onLocationChanged

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm targeting Google API 2.3.3 and have the following test class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

public class MockLocationManagerTests extends AndroidTestCase implements LocationListener{

    private static final String TAG = "MockLocationTests";
    private String locationProvider = "TestProvider";
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location lastLocation;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         if (Settings.Secure.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 0) == 0) {
                 fail("Mock location must be enabled");
        }
        setupLocationManager();
    }

    private void setupLocationManager() {
        if (locationManager.getProvider(locationProvider) != null) {
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(locationProvider);
        }

        locationManager.addTestProvider(locationProvider, 
                                        false, 
                                        true, 
                                        false, 
                                        false, 
                                        false, 
                                        false, 
                                        false, 
                                        Criteria.POWER_LOW, 
                                        Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(locationProvider, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(locationProvider, true);
    }

    private Location createLocation(double lat, double lon) {
        Location location = new Location(locationProvider);
        location.setLatitude(lat);
        location.setLongitude(lon);
        location.setAltitude(0);
        location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return location;
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public final void testCanObserveLocationChanging() throws InterruptedException {
        Location l = createLocation(19,-2);
        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(locationProvider,l);
        synchronized(this){
            wait(5000);
        }
        Location l2 = createLocation(1,-10);
        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(locationProvider,l2);
        synchronized(this){
            wait(5000);
        }
        assertEquals(l,lastLocation);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG,"location changed");
        lastLocation = location;        
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.i(TAG, provider+" disabled");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.i(TAG, provider+" enabled");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i(TAG,"status changed: "+provider+" to "+status);
    }
}
```

onLocationChanged is not being called and my google-fu and brain-fu is failing me. Any advice greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

none of the log messages are caught so onStatusChanged and onProviderEnabled aren't firing?

If I call `getLastKnownLocation()` between calls to `setTestProviderLocation()` the locationManager returns the location I've set

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

If I add the class that utilises this code to my application then onLocationChanged() is called.
The only difference being that I'm not using a Mock_Location.
So it does seem that setTestProviderLocation() is not causing onLocationChanged() to fire

Comment: Are you using the emulator or a phone? I don't see anything wrong either. I'm assuming you've added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
` permission

Comment: This is using the emulator and yep, have set the Mock location permission.

Answer (score 1):

Behaves same way on Google API 19.

The AndroidTestCase doesn't setup a proper Looper for handling of the update events. You have to run it as a test activity ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or add a ThreadLooper to the AndroidTestCase to deal with the update messages.

```
Looper mLooper; 
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("LocationHandlerThread");
thread.start(); // starts the thread.
mLooper = thread.getLooper();
```

Then use the new Looper in the requestLocationUpdates method:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener, mLooper);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable mock locations on your phone or emulator?
There is a setting for this in applications/development/mock locations.

Comment: It is enabled yep. I'm thinking this is a bug with setTestProviderLocation not calling onLocationChanged as the exact same class as is under test works when on the emulator. It only doesn't 'work' when it's run from a test.

Answer (score -1):

Just click "Send" at the emulator control tab of the eclipse to send coordinates to the app.[image]

Comment: I'm trying to setup *automated* testing. I've since moved to using robolectric and roboguice so I never actually solved this